# how to instal snmp server in redhat linux?

Tags: snmp, snmpd, net-snmp

I am having some problem with snmp server installation.I want to install snmp server and agent also by which i can query to my local host.

i have downloaded the snmp tar version as I want to write a program to get some data from a device and I did that ,but when I want to check the localhost data it is not showing as I didn't install snmp or activated snmp on my linux ,

I have downloaded and install following

http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.1/ and from here the net-snmp-5.7.1.tar.gz file.

but this gives me only the library and header to program but when I am searching for snmp service it is not running .

so kindly tell me what to do or what to do for snmp daemon to run.I searched for the binaries but it is not for redhat .so kindly tell me some thing for this.

Thnaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about installing from source code; packages are already available.

```
yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
```

Comment: You should either pay for your Red Hat subscription, or use CentOS or another clone.

Comment: Hi it sowing following error : root@vivekv-thinkpad-r400 wshare]# yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package net-snmp available.
No package net-snmp-utils available.
Nothing to do
[root@vivekv-thi

Comment: refer to comment 1.